# Is there a way to explicitly reference a non-static inner class instance?

Tags: java, android, anonymous-inner-class

You can explicitly reference the class instance for a top-level class as below:

```
public class Dog {
  public void subscribeDogToTreats() {
    Set<?> listenerSet = map.get("treats");
    listenerSet.add(Dog.this);
    map.put("treats", listenerSet);
  }
}
```

However, if you try to reference this from within an anonymous inner class with the intention of this being a reference to the anonymous inner class. Using the same naming pattern you'll receive the error "is not an enclosing class." For example:

```
public class Dog {
  void initializeHunger() {
    OnHungerChangeListener listener = new OnHungerChangeListener() {
      public void onHungerChanged(int stomachCapacity) {
       if(stomachCapacity == Stomach.FULL) {
         stomach.removeOnHungerChangeListener(OnHungerChangeListener.this);
       }
     }
   }
   stomach.addOnHunderChangeListener(listener);
```

The real-world example of where I would like to do this is for adding OnPageChangeListeners to viewpagers and removing them after a transition has completed in Android. I know that the keyword this references the anonymous inner class, but when I run into situations like this I have to prove this to myself by printing out the class name. I am terrified of having a hard-to-catch bug where I am referencing the outer class instance where I meant to reference the inner or vice versa.

I would prefer to always use Dog.this or InnerClass.this to be explicit and am wondering if there is a way to do this for non-static inner classes or how other developers handle this (in Android Studio, both this references are color-coded the same). Other than remembering that this always refers to the most inner class instance in scope, is there a way to make that explicit?

Answer (score 0):

What you described is what you have to do according the Java language specs.  There's no way to alter the meaning of `this` in Java, and no way to change the qualification of an enclosing class, if that's what you're trying to do.  You can always make your own local variables as a shortcut, if that helps you.